# Bootstrap Navbar won't expand

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, navbar

I used the code in Bootstrap 4 documentation to make my own navbar.
The Bootstrap navbar manages to collapse just fine but it just won't expand when I click the button.
I've included jQuery, JavaScript, and Bootstrap 4 JavaScript in this pen but it just doesn't work.
Is there anything wrong with the code?

This is my code: https://codepen.io/lamtu/pen/LdRLWv

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lam Tu</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">    
      <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
      <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href="#porfolio">Porfolio</a></li>
      <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href="#social">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct version of `popper.js`:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js

Navbar working: https://www.codeply.com/go/nU7rkG4Lu0

Comment: I added the above file and it still doesn't work. Don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Working on my portfolio project on https://freecodecamp.org I had a similar issue to this but fixed it. This is what my code looks like;

```
    <div class= "w-100>
    <nav class= "navbar nav-fill navbar-expand- 
    lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
```

The w-100 means a width of 100%. But if this  doesn't suffice please view my entire code especially the section after the button;

```
    <div class="justify-content-end collapse navbar-collapse" 
    id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
```

Here is my link, just incase you need futher help or see something you like;

https://codepen.io/stealthman22/full/PeZvNK/

Cheers and happy coding!